# how to echo out if multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
array (size=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'produs' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'prajitura cu nuca' (length=17)
          1 => string 'prajitura cu morcovi' (length=20)
          2 => string 'prajitura cu morcovi' (length=20)
      'creatorchoise' => int 9
      'ambalaj' => string 'caserola' (length=8)
      'capacitate' => string '15' (length=2)
      'cantitate' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'produs' => string 'prajitura cu nuca' (length=17)
      'creatorchoise' => int 28
      'ambalaj' => string 'platou' (length=6)
      'capacitate' => string '30' (length=2)
      'cantitate' => string '1' (length=1)
```

i want to echo out values so i made this

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cos'] as $key => $value){

    $creatorchoise = $value['creatorchoise'];  
    $ambalaj = $value['ambalaj'];
    $capacitate = $value['capacitate'];
    $cantitate = $value['cantitate'];

    if (!is_array($value['produs'])){

        $produs = $value['produs'];

    } else {

         foreach ($value['produs'] as $row => $produs){



         }
    echo "produs: " . $produs . " /ambalaj: " . $ambalaj . " / capacitate: " . $capacitate . " / cantitate: " . $cantitate . "<br>";        
    }
```

the problem starts when the product is array, i know im echoing out of the product array loop

any sugestions?

Comment: I think you have to echo the produs inside the foreach `echo "produs: " . $produs;` or use implode.

Comment: Which "problem starts"? What have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$produs` is an array, you should access the value inside the foreach

```
foreach ($value['produs'] as $row => $produs){
    // access $produs here
}
```

If you want to echo all the values from the array using a delimiter, you could also use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$produs = "";
if (!is_array($value['produs'])){
    $produs = $value['produs'];
} else {
    $produs = implode(',', $value['produs']);
}

echo "produs: " . $produs . " /ambalaj: " . $ambalaj . " / capacitate: " . $capacitate . " / cantitate: " . $cantitate . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could coerce the string to an array:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    [
        'products' => 'Gold and shiny'
    ],
    [
        'products' => [
            'Silver beads',
            'Green emeralds'
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($data as $item) {
    $products = (array) $item['products'];
    foreach($products as $product) {
        echo $product, "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Gold and shiny
Silver beads
Green emeralds
```

Comment: and how would you do it for  output: '[1. Gold and shiny, 2. Silver beads, Green emeralds]' ?

Comment: @btz out of scope of your original question.  Feel free to edit your question with your desired outputs for various concrete inputs.